# AWS Kinesis putRecords in synchronous way using NodeJS SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-kinesis, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to writ data to Amazon Kinesis using AWS SDK for NodeJS. I am using putRecords method which I want to use with async/await. I need to preform few other steps once the records are written to Kinesis. I want this to be a synchronous process, so I cannot use just callbacks.

I have tried few different ways using promise, async/await but none of them seem to be working.

With Async/Await:

```
let response = await kinesisPutRecords({ 
    Records: //records,
    StreamName: //streamName
});

async function kinesisPutRecords(recordsParams){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{

        kinesisClient.putRecords(recordsParams,function (err, data) {
            if (err) 
                reject(err);
            resolve();        
        }
    });
}
```

With Promise

```
let response = await kinesisClient.putRecords(recordsParams).promise();
console.log(response);
```

This approaches are used inside a loop, the loop continues without waiting for this call to finish.

These two approaches work fine with S3.getObject();

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

### Update 1:

I found the problem with the above code. Its just missing try...catch block is causing the issue. In my full code, I still have this issue but I was able to find the root cause.

I am using [csv tarnsform](https://csv.js.org/transform/) with NodeJS streams. Inside the transform function, await is not working. May be because of the fact that stream is async and do not pause?

Code close to my scenario:

```
const transformer = transform(function (record) {
    //add records to an array until a threshold is met and then push to kinesis.
       
let response = await kinesisPutRecords();
console.log(response);
    
}, function(err, output){
  //logic to push remaining records
});

fileReadStream
   .pipe(gunzip) //unzip the file
   .pipe(csvParser) //to parse the csv
   .pipe(transformer);


async function kinesisPutRecords(recordsParams){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
       try{
           kinesisClient.putRecords(recordsParams,function (err, data) {
               if (err) 
                  reject(err);
               resolve();        
           });
       }
       catch(exception ex){
           reject();
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: doesn't aws kinesis client has async on its own?